# Angular JS ng-change not triggered for select dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

I am facing an issue with dropdown change event in Angular JS.
ng-change event is sometimes not fired.

```
<tr ng-repeat="Item in Items">
    <td>
        <select id="abc" ng-model="Item.Value" 
                ng-change="Change('P1',P2,{{Items.length}})" 
                ng-options="Val for Val in Options">
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Can anyone please explain whats wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you need the `{{}}` around the `Items.length`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 <select id="abc" ng-model="Item.Value" ng-change="Change('P1',P2,Items.length)" ng-options="Val for Val in Options">
```

You don't need `{{ }}`, since `ng-change` expects an expression.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

## html

```
 <tr ng-repeat="Item in Items">
  <td>
    <select id="abc" ng-model="Item.Value"
    ng-change="Change('P1',P2,Items)" ng-options="Val for Val in Options">
    </select>
   </td>
</tr>
```

inside script file

## js

$scope.Change = function(value1,value2,items)
   {

```
  var itemsLength = items.length;
  //here you will get length of items,dont use {{}}  inside function
```

}